# Windows hosted Django application Suddenly stopped working

Tags: django, python-2.7, iis-8, internal-server-error

I have an django web application which having 2 applications. One application renders the page by accessing the `server_url` and other one is accessed by passing `server_url/applicaion_name`. I used Django 1.8.4 and python 2.7.10 for the development and hosted in iis 8.5.

The application was working fine for pass 2+ months and out of the blue, application started throwing.

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

c:\Python27\python.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
```

Here comes the tricky part. Error is coming only while accessing the server URl(renders home page previously) and app hosted in erver_url/applicaion_name is still working fine.

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

UPDATE:

I managed to get logs from IIS and when the page loads and throws 500, it provides the below details.

```
wfastcgi.py 3.0.0 started
Python version: 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
wfastcgi.py 3.0.0 initializing
wfastcgi.py will restart when files in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\ are changed: .*((\.py)|(\.config))$
wfastcgi.py 3.0.0 initialized
wfastcgi.py exiting because Myapp\views.py has changed, matching .*((\.py)|(\.config))$
Running on_exit tasks
```

In `FastCGI Settings` i have add the following parameters.

```
Fullpath: C:\Python27\python.exe
Arguments : C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi-3.0.0-py2.7.egg\wfastcgi.py
Environmental variables : DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE:MySite.Settings
                          PYTHONPATH:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite
                          WSGI_HANDLER:django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: you need to look at your django logs, because HTTP 500 just means your Django app (probably) throws an exception. Without logs it's not possible to debug.

Comment: Updated the request with IIS Logs and FastCGI Settings.